# Why does exchangelib not work on pythonanywhere?

Tags: python, pythonanywhere, exchangelib

I've used the exchangelib package for years, but it does not seem to work on pythonanywhere. I run the identical script on my local mac (which runs predictably well and normally) but on PA the stdout trace output says my creds are wrong, eventhough they are definitively correct. Notes:

1. I ran the script from the proper environment on pythonanywhere
2. I have a paid account on pythonanywhere, so no IPs/domains should be blacklisted AFAIK.
3. Attached is a screen grab of the stdout having run the test code successfully on my mac.
4. I contacted pythonanywhere about the issue but they insisted my creds must be wrong.
5. Here is the test code:

```
    from exchangelib import DELEGATE, IMPERSONATION, Account, Credentials, Configuration, FaultTolerance
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig()
    log = logging.getLogger()
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    def connect_to_EWS(_USERNAME_, _PASS_, _PRIMARY_SMTP_ADDRESS_):

        creds = Credentials(_USERNAME_,_PASS_)

        config = Configuration(credentials=creds, server='outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx')
    
        return Account(
        primary_smtp_address=_PRIMARY_SMTP_ADDRESS_,
        autodiscover=False, 
        config = config,
        access_type=DELEGATE
        )
    
    account = connect_to_EWS("username", "pswd", "pri_smtp_address")

    for item in account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:10]:
        print(item.subject, item.sender, item.datetime_received)
```

6. And finally, here is the trace output from the stdout on pythonanywhere:

```
    (Ankwil_Beta_Env) 16:58 ~/ankwilbeta001 (main)$ python exchangelib_patrick.py
DEBUG:exchangelib.protocol:Waiting for _protocol_cache_lock
DEBUG:exchangelib.protocol:Protocol __call__ cache miss. Adding key '('https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx/EWS/Exchange.asmx', Credentials('pkstacey@outlook.com', '********'))'
DEBUG:exchangelib.transport:Requesting b'<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'utf-8\'?>\n<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"><s:Header><t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2019"/></s:Header><s:Body><m:ResolveNames ReturnFullContactData="false"><m:UnresolvedEntry>pkstacey@outlook.com</m:UnresolvedEntry></m:ResolveNames></s:Body></s:Envelope>' from https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx/EWS/Exchange.asmx
DEBUG:exchangelib.transport:Trying to get service auth type for https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx/EWS/Exchange.asmx
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): outlook.office365.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://outlook.office365.com:443 "POST /EWS/Exchange.asmx/EWS/Exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1" 401 0
DEBUG:exchangelib.transport:Request headers: {'User-Agent': 'exchangelib/4.6.2 (python-requests/2.26.0)', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length': '463'}
DEBUG:exchangelib.transport:Response headers: {'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/10.0', 'request-id': 'c79f0912-fa68-5081-e0f1-ae8954057853', 'Alt-Svc': 'h3=":443",h3-29=":443"', 'X-FirstHopCafeEFZ': 'MNZ', 'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET', 'X-FEServer': 'BL1PR13CA0190', 'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic Realm=""', 'Date': 'Mon, 21 Feb 2022 16:58:32 GMT', 'Content-Length': '0'}
DEBUG:exchangelib.transport:realm: 
DEBUG:exchangelib.transport:Auth type is basic
DEBUG:exchangelib.version:Asking server for version info using API version Exchange2019
DEBUG:exchangelib.services.common:Processing chunk 1 containing 1 items
DEBUG:exchangelib.services.common:Calling service ResolveNames
DEBUG:exchangelib.services.common:Trying API version Exchange2019
DEBUG:exchangelib.protocol:Server outlook.office365.com: Increasing session pool size from 0 to 1
DEBUG:exchangelib.protocol:Server outlook.office365.com: Created session 26528
DEBUG:exchangelib.protocol:Server outlook.office365.com: Waiting for session
DEBUG:exchangelib.protocol:Server outlook.office365.com: Got session 26528
DEBUG:exchangelib.util:Session 26528 thread 139771968923456: retry 0 timeout 120 POST'ing to https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx/EWS/Exchange.asmx after 10s wait
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): outlook.office365.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://outlook.office365.com:443 "POST /EWS/Exchange.asmx/EWS/Exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1" 401 0
DEBUG:exchangelib.util:Retry: 0
Waited: 10
Timeout: 120
Session: 26528
Thread: 139771968923456
Auth type: <requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth object at 0x7f1f2ea15e10>
URL: https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx/EWS/Exchange.asmx
HTTP adapter: <requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter object at 0x7f1f2ea15450>
Allow redirects: False
Streaming: False
Response time: 0.30712076199415606
Status code: 401
Request headers: {'User-Agent': 'exchangelib/4.6.2 (python-requests/2.26.0)', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length': '463', 'Authorization': 'Basic cGtzdGFjZXlAb3V0bG9vay5jb206ZDMzcHRoMG5nT3V0bG9vaw=='}
Response headers: {'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/10.0', 'request-id': '13126a04-5ecb-9622-86b9-7ead817593b4', 'Alt-Svc': 'h3=":443",h3-29=":443"', 'X-CalculatedFETarget': 'CWLP123CU010.internal.outlook.com', 'X-BackEndHttpStatus': '401, 401', 'Set-Cookie': 'exchangecookie=c2da6958e6a342b4a11ad5adc3e5e940; expires=Tue, 21-Feb-2023 16:58:32 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly', 'X-FEProxyInfo': 'CWLP123CA0222.GBRP123.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM', 'X-CalculatedBETarget': 'CWLP123MB5491.GBRP123.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM', 'X-RUM-Validated': '1', 'X-BeSku': 'WCS6', 'X-DiagInfo': 'CWLP123MB5491', 'X-BEServer': 'CWLP123MB5491', 'X-Proxy-RoutingCorrectness': '1', 'X-Proxy-BackendServerStatus': '401', 'X-FEServer': 'CWLP123CA0222, BL1PR13CA0192', 'X-FirstHopCafeEFZ': 'MNZ', 'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET', 'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic Realm=""', 'Date': 'Mon, 21 Feb 2022 16:58:31 GMT', 'Content-Length': '0'}
DEBUG:exchangelib.util.xml:Request XML: b'<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'utf-8\'?>\n<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"><s:Header><t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2019"/></s:Header><s:Body><m:ResolveNames ReturnFullContactData="false"><m:UnresolvedEntry>pkstacey@outlook.com</m:UnresolvedEntry></m:ResolveNames></s:Body></s:Envelope>'
Response XML: b''
DEBUG:exchangelib.protocol:No retry: no fail-fast policy
DEBUG:exchangelib.protocol:Server outlook.office365.com: Retiring session 26528
DEBUG:exchangelib.protocol:Server outlook.office365.com: Created session 23658
DEBUG:exchangelib.protocol:Server outlook.office365.com: Releasing session 23658
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exchangelib_patrick.py", line 22, in <module>
    account = connect_to_EWS("pkstacey@outlook.com", "<hidden>", "pkstacey@outlook.com")
2006/types"><s:Header><t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2019"/></s:Header><s:Body><m:ResolveNames ReturnFullContactData="false"><m:
  File "exchangelib_patrick.py", line 19, in connect_to_EWS
    access_type=DELEGATE
  File "/home/ankwilitas/.virtualenvs/Ankwil_Beta_Env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/exchangelib/account.py", line 136, in __init__
    self.version = self.protocol.version
  File "/home/ankwilitas/.virtualenvs/Ankwil_Beta_Env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/exchangelib/protocol.py", line 470, in version
    self.config.version = Version.guess(self, api_version_hint=self._api_version_hint)
  File "/home/ankwilitas/.virtualenvs/Ankwil_Beta_Env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/exchangelib/version.py", line 229, in guess
    list(ResolveNames(protocol=protocol).call(unresolved_entries=[name]))
  File "/home/ankwilitas/.virtualenvs/Ankwil_Beta_Env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/exchangelib/services/resolve_names.py", line 52, in _ele
ms_to_objs
    for elem in elems:
  File "/home/ankwilitas/.virtualenvs/Ankwil_Beta_Env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/exchangelib/services/common.py", line 206, in _chunked_g
et_elements
    yield from self._get_elements(payload=payload_func(chunk, **kwargs))
  File "/home/ankwilitas/.virtualenvs/Ankwil_Beta_Env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/exchangelib/services/common.py", line 226, in _get_eleme
nts
    yield from self._response_generator(payload=payload)
  File "/home/ankwilitas/.virtualenvs/Ankwil_Beta_Env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/exchangelib/services/common.py", line 190, in _response_
generator
    response = self._get_response_xml(payload=payload)
  File "/home/ankwilitas/.virtualenvs/Ankwil_Beta_Env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/exchangelib/services/common.py", line 312, in _get_respo
nse_xml
    r = self._get_response(payload=payload, api_version=api_version)
  File "/home/ankwilitas/.virtualenvs/Ankwil_Beta_Env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/exchangelib/services/common.py", line 279, in _get_respo
nse
    timeout=self.timeout or self.protocol.TIMEOUT,
  File "/home/ankwilitas/.virtualenvs/Ankwil_Beta_Env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/exchangelib/util.py", line 877, in post_ratelimited
    protocol.retry_policy.raise_response_errors(r)  # Always raises an exception
  File "/home/ankwilitas/.virtualenvs/Ankwil_Beta_Env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/exchangelib/protocol.py", line 689, in raise_response_er
rors
    raise UnauthorizedError('Invalid credentials for %s' % response.url)
exchangelib.errors.UnauthorizedError: Invalid credentials for https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx/EWS/Exchange.asmx
DEBUG:exchangelib.protocol:Server outlook.office365.com: Closing sessions
(Ankwil_Beta_Env) 16:58 ~/ankwilbeta001 (main)$
```

Comment: Aw shucks, this was minus one'd but without subjective explanation... I also know others have had the same issue but remains unresolved...

Comment: You should reach out to the developer who might know more about the issue https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/issues

Comment: He regularly responds here to similar questions, and this query may be in the public interest. Let's see. Thanks.